# Salesforce want to pass values from list to JSON to call API

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex

Hello Salesforce developers,

From the SOQL list I have created in the below code, I want to pass email and name to the json i have serialised. Please let me know why I am I not able to put them throuh

APEX:

```
public class SampleMaroPost {
    public static string sendEmailThroughMaro(string myInpEmail) {
        string successContacts = '';
        string failureContacts = '';
        Date d = Date.Today().addDays(15);
        list<Account> conts = new list<Account> ([SELECT name, Email_FLP_com__c  from account where ID IN
(select Distributor__c from Stripe_Subscripton__c where Start_Date__c = TODAY AND Actual_End_Date__c = : d AND Status__c='active' ) AND  Email_FLP_com__c != NULL LIMIT 1]);

        overallEmail myEmail = new overallEmail();
        for(Account c : conts){
            myEmail.email.campaign_id = 172;
            myEmail.email.contact.Email = c.Email_FLP_com__c;
            myEmail.email.contact.first_name = c.name;
            system.debug('#### Input JSON: ' + JSON.serialize(myEmail));
```

JSON Used:

```
{
  "email": {
    "campaign_id": 172,
    "contact": {
      "email": "x1testa@gmail.com",
      "first_name": "Test_naresh"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the entire code when used with hard coded Name and email this is working would like to query our records and insert in "Name" "Email" and then send them in batched.

```
public class sampleMaroPost1 {
    public list<Account> autorenewal {set;get;}
        public void renewal(){

            Date d = Date.Today().addDays(15);
            autorenewal = [SELECT ID, Email__c, name, Provision_Date__c, Email_FLP_com__c  from account where ID IN
(select Distributor__c from Stripe_Subscripton__c where Actual_End_Date__c = :d  AND Status__c='active' ) AND  Email_FLP_com__c != NULL limit 1];


    }
    public static maroResponse sendEmailThroughMaro(string myInpEmail) {


        //Contact c = [SELECT Id ,LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'vineeth.anirush@gmail.com'];    
        string resultBodyGet = '';
        overallEmail myEmail = new overallEmail();
        myEmail.email.campaign_id = 174;
        myEmail.email.contact.email = 'shrikant.bhise@nextsphere.com'; //c.Email;
        myEmail.email.contact.first_name = 'Swetha'; //c.LastName;
        Map<String, String> tags = new Map<String, String>();
        tags.put('firstName', 'Swetha');
        myEmail.email.tags = tags;
        system.debug('#### Input JSON: ' + JSON.serialize(myEmail));
        String endpoint = 'http://api.maropost.com/accounts/1173/emails/deliver.json?auth_token=j-V4sx8ueUT7eKM8us_Cz5JqXBzoRrNS3p1lEZyPUPGcwWNoVNZpKQ';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        req.setbody(JSON.serialize(myEmail));
        Http http = new Http();
        try{
            system.debug('Sending email');
            HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
            system.debug('sent email');
             resultBodyGet = response.getBody();  
            system.debug('Output response:' + resultBodyGet);
            maroResponse myMaroResponse = new maroResponse();
        }
        catch (exception e){
            system.debug('#### exception: ' + e.getMessage());
        }

        maroResponse myMaroResponse = new maroResponse();

       if(resultBodyGet != null && resultBodyGet != '') 
       {
         myMaroResponse = (maroResponse) JSON.deserialize(resultBodyGet, maroResponse.class);
       }


        system.debug('#### myMaroResponse: ' + myMaroResponse);      

        return myMaroResponse;        

    }   

    public class maroResponse {
        public string message {get;set;}
    }

    public class overallEmail {
        public emailJson email = new emailJson();
    }

    public class emailJson {
        public Integer campaign_id;
        public contactJson contact = new contactJson();
        public Map<String, String> tags;
    }

    public class contactJson {
        public string email;
        public string first_name;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no data on the 16th date. I used 
`Date d = Date.Today().addDays(14);` instead of

```
Date d = Date.Today().addDays(15);
```

Thank you